# Is there a good way to buffer large video files with media elements js player in Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, preload, buffering

I'm being forced to use rather large videos within an html 5 video player and I can't seen ti get the buffering to work while playing in Chrome on both a Mac and PC.

The player buffers great in Firefox and Safari, not sure about IE being on a mac.

I'm using the following code in the video tags:

```
video mp4="http://xeroproject.com/sqwm/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/benefits.mp4" ogg="http://xeroproject.com/sqwm/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/benefits.ogg" webm="http://xeroproject.com/sqwm/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/benefits.webm" poster="http://xeroproject.com/sqwm/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/slide.jpg" preload="none" width="820" height="462" captions="http://xeroproject.com/sqwm/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/intro.srt
```

And the video player can be viewed [**here**](http://xeroproject.com/sqwm/benefits/)

I've also ready that Chrome's initial preload is only around 2mb as opposed to FF and Safari which are around 10mb, which would explain slower buffer, but the videos get to a point and then just stopp buffering in Chrome and stick.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The buffer works nice in my chrome browser. Doh! after 2:08 minute the buffer no longer works. :(

Comment: Depending on your connection speed it seems to stop around 1:00 or 2:00. I've tried setting preload to true, also I've tried several different ways to encode the files: Handbreak, Miro and Quicktime Pro.

Comment: did you check max post size or something?

Comment: I haven't found anything on max size yet as far as what can be played I've only seen anything on preload MB. Do you know of any documentation?